# Unable to Load Image via PictureBox.ImageLocation with Direct URL

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm encountering an issue while trying to dynamically load and display an image in a PictureBox using the `ImageLocation` property. I have the following code snippet:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png";
```

However, the image is not being displayed, and the PictureBox remains empty. I have verified that the URL is correct and that the image is accessible.

I've tried using other methods, such as loading the image into a MemoryStream and setting PictureBox.Image directly, and it works fine. But I'm specifically interested in using ImageLocation.

Is there anything specific I need to consider or configure when using ImageLocation with a direct URL? Are there limitations or known issues with this approach? Any insights or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
i found out that normal `ImageLocation` is working fine but when i use it in a loop it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load image from URL to pictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969058/load-image-from-url-to-picturebox)

Comment: @jarmanso7 I found that before posting the question.

Comment: Show all relevant code! Doe s the loop go over different pboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer...
In a loop i have to use this instead (in a loop that image is taken and image is null):

```
pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
pictureBox.ImageLocation = textBox.Text;
pictureBox.LoadCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    pictureBox.Invalidate();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below methods :

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png");

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
}
```

or providing url location

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png"
```

or else :

```
pictureBox1.Load("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png");
```

Lastly, if nothing works only way is to add the image to your resources. and provide the path

Comment: tried it but i don't want to include System.Net in my project

Comment: If above method does not try adding it to your resources and provide path